# Java synchronized return when a network call finishes

Tags: java, android, synchronization, retrofit2

I have a method `intercept` which expects a Response object in return.

```
@Override
public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
    Request original = chain.request();
    mRequestBuilder = original.newBuilder();

    mAgent.getToken(new OnTokenResponse() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(final String token) {
            mRequestBuilder.removeHeader(AUTHORIZATION);
            mRequestBuilder.header(AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer " + token);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(final String error) {

        }
    });

    Request request = mRequestBuilder.build();
    return chain.proceed(request);
}
```

`mAgent.getToken()` makes a network call and returns a string in onSuccess if succeeded. Which in turn, I add as header to `mRequestBuilder`.
Now since, the network call will take some time to finish, I want to execute `Request request = mRequestBuilder.build()` only after the network call is completed (either success or failure).

How can I synchronize this operation?

Comment: @SantanuSur because onSuccess has void return type. You can't return anything from that method.

Comment: @GhostCat No it is not. And since it's part of library code, I can not sync that.

Comment: @Rajkiran For the record: your comment about "void" return type misses the point. You pass an anonymous inner class to `getToken()`. Your code doesn't call these methods, therefore your code doesn't receive a potential result, even if `onSuccess()` would return something!

Comment: @GhostCat where is your answer? Also, your comment is deleted which had a suggestion.

Comment: @Rajkiran have added an answer.. hope it helps..

Answer (score -1):

> I want to execute Request `request = mRequestBuilder.build()` only after
>   the network call is completed (either success or failure).
>
> How can I synchronize this operation?

You either wait (block) until the network call completed, or you do `request = mRequestBuilder.build();...` in the callback itself.

Waiting/blocking is not a good idea if you do it on the main/GUI thread.

Running code inside the callback is probably not a good idea too, because the callback probably runs in some networking thread, and you definitely should not call `chain.proceed()` on that thread.

So the only clean way to do it is to run the network request at some appropriate point/time to obtain the result first, and only after that result is available allow the code to be called that depends on it.

I deliberately don't include an example of how to block waiting for a signal from an asynchronous callback here because you really shouldn't use this kind of blocking if it might happen to run on the GUI thread.

Comment: How would the interceptor return response ? If the builder is inside the call back method ?